# What binary prefix, JEDEC or IEC, is used for calculating networking gear speed

Tags: speed, testing

### What is the common practice of calculating a speed of an ethernet enabled device, and which standard (IEC or JEDEC) is used?

I'm developing and testing a product that is interconnected via ethernet.

The test is basically sending several thousand packets, of specified "effective" size in bytes (without the header), and receiving a time it takes to process all of them.

My intentions are to get a speed that can be compared to a speed of a switch or a router.

I'm confused by how is the resulting speed calculated.

The base equation in my case is:

```
(packet_size * packet_count) / time_total = speed_in_Bps
```

But when i neet to get *Mb/s* is it:

```
(speed_in_Bps * 8) / (1024 ^ 2)
```

or:

```
(speed_in_Bps * 8) / (10 ^ (3 * 2))
```

or is it some other way that these speeds are calculated?

An example of results with 256MB * 10000 packets processed at 300ms, the fist one gives me speed of 65.1 *Mb/s* and the second one gives 68.2 *Mb/s*

Comment: did you have a look at [iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf)?

Comment: @JFL that is great, but my use case requires a lot of processing on both ends, which has to be taken into account, and so i can't use it.

Comment: Ok, I was actually wondering if you were measuring the network performance or the hosts processing time.

Comment: When discussing network speed, you use powers of 10, not powers of 2, for measuring. For example, 1000 bps is 1 Kbps; don't use 1024 bps as 1 Kbps. Also, ethernet has a lot of overhead with the Preamble, SoF Delimiter, Frame Header, FCS, and Inter-packet Gap.

Comment: If you're using TCP for transport, the L1+L2+L3+L4 overhead per packet is 78 bytes. So, if you're using MTU-sized packets, 1460 payload create a 1538 byte Ethernet packet + IPG on the wire with a maximum throughput of 118.66 MB/s per gigabit link speed. If you're using "raw" Ethernet, the overhead reduces to 38 bytes with a payload of 1500 bytes (121.9 MB/s per Gbit/s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED

Despite the extended usage of binary in computer world and power of two based units (Byte, 32-bits word etc...), network bandwidth is commonly expressed in power of ten units.

So it is `(speed_in_Bps * 8) / (10 ^ (3 * 2))` (or /50^3)

Comment: Are you sure? I have never seen bandwith being calculated as powers of 2, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units seems to agree.

Comment: @TeunVink you're right. Shame on me... it's the other way around.

Comment: No worries :) I suggest you fix your answer, especially since it got accepted.

Comment: @JFL Thanks for fixing it, even tho it made me confused for a while ;)

Comment: It absolute makes no sense to use binary prefixes in communications. Binary prefixes only make sense where sizes are naturally based on the binary system, ie. in RAM. They're also historically used for storage (HDDs, file sizes) in various OSes but that doesn't make too much sense either. However, they're never (seriously) used for communication, not even historically.

Comment: @Zac67 any digital medium uses binary prefixes except for HDDs, but you won't see much of it, because most of that is hidden from user. The reason for this is almost all digital devices take 8bit or Byte as the smallest data unit. The problem comes from the IEC since they just made up standard because HDD manufacturers were putting disk sizes in decimal prefixes where as every other medium has in binary prefix.

Comment: @The ninja employee Hardware doesn't use any prefixes, prefixes are for humans. And they should be used as is practical, not as is traditional. A HDD's size has absolutely no relation to any binary base. It's a result of technological, engineering, cost and marketing considerations.

Comment: Only the total disk size given by the manufacturer is in decimal unit. All operating systems display only binary prefixes for disk-related sizes.

Comment: @Zac67 What i meant by it, you set an address or page in your medium that is set by command or physical pins, everything uses these, sd cards, compact flash, ccd/cmos sensors, SSDs, RAM, cash, LCDs, ETH-phy (RMII,MII), pcie (in DMA mode), ETC. HDDs don't use this since they're to certain extent analog (i.e. the data can be placed anywhere on the disk), which means a manufacturer can make a 2TB or a 1.8TB disk, but they can label it the same way.

Comment: All hardware is analog at the lowest level. Block-storage devices have data blocks (512 B or 4KiB) as smallest access unit. The situation is no different with HDDs, SSDs, SD cards, USB sticks etc as with communications.